# Having trouble using the filter function in R

Tags: r

The question I am given to answer is:

in the state of Maryland, which two counties occur most frequently in the dataset?

In my data set there is a column called 'States' that contains state abbreviations in them. I am having trouble only displaying the frequency of the counties that are only in Maryland

This is what I have so far:

```
hw1_dataset_for_msully56 %>%
  filter(State == MD) %>%
  group_by(County) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  arrange(-n)
```

Comment: I think it is `filter(State == 'MD')` i.e you need quotes around MD

Comment: Try `filter(State == 'MD')`

Answer (score 0):

We need quotes around the `MD` as `"MD"`

```
hw1_dataset_for_msully56 %>%
     filter(State == "MD") %>%
     group_by(County) %>%
     summarise(n = n()) %>%
     arrange(-n)
```

---

Also, instead of `group_by/summarise`, it can be simplified with `count`

```
hw1_dataset_for_msully56 %>%
     filter(State == 'MD') %>%
     count(County) %>%
     arrange(-n)
```